# Single PHP page hosting

Tags: php, node.js, amazon-ec2, hosting

I am developing APIs in node js and have hosted the application on amazon EC2. In a third party API it is required to host a php page on our server and give its public url back to them. Is there another way to host it apart from a LAMP setup? Anything apart from EC2 is also fine but please take into consideration that this is a single page having some logic and nothing else will be there in PHP.

Comment: Any web server with PHP installed will be able to host a PHP page.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking! Maybe its just me, but could you try and make your question more clear

Comment: You can install php on EC2. You dont necessarily need apache, you can just use node to call php cli and pass the response back. Another alternative is to just translate the php to node instead - the 3rd party calling code just requires the response it gets back to be a certain format. Without seeing the php in question though its hard to help

Comment: Thank you for the replies friends. That resolves my query.

Answer (score 1):

I work with node and php. I would recommend NGINX. It's configuration files are really simple and it's much lighter-weight than apache.

You can simply create a redirect/rewrite directive in NGINX that will pass your php page to the node server instead and be done. For this usecase, you wouldn't actually even need to install or configure the PHP backend.

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#proxy

You might also check AWS domain management tools (AWS Route 53). There may be a way to directly rewrite the incoming PHP request to go to your node app instead without installing any webserver on your EC2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are other web-servers available apart from apache: For instance [Nginx plus](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx-plus-aws/) or [Lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/), both are fine and lightweight alternatives to host your PHP files on EC2.

Though, it's not clear to me why don't you like the LAMP setup. Maybe Apache+PHP, without MySQL, would be enough for you?